# Why fixed element gets out of viewport on zoom-in (iPad)?

Tags: javascript, css, ios, safari, css-position

http://jsfiddle.net/viebel/BBjzn/show/ - here is a simple example with two `fixed` elements (in two corners of the page). IF I get it right, the two fixed elements should always be in a viewport. Even when zooming-in. OR, at least, this is the situation with desktop browser (chrome).

However, when running the same code on iPad (iOS 5) and zooming in there are two phases: first, everything goes as expected, but if zoom-in continues, the two `fixed` elements are floating out of the viewport.

Does this behaviour follow the specification? What I really should expect? And, of course, what do I need to do to keep the elements always in a viewport?

IF anything is unclear - please ask - I'll be more than happy to clarify. The jsfiddle sample code to play with is here: http://jsfiddle.net/viebel/BBjzn/

Comment: `position:fixed` didn't work on iPhone some time ago. Maybe, it still doesn't work in `iOS`.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.quirksmode.org/m/css.html
There you can exactly see what works where and how.

In your special case, the reason for the behavior is, that the position:fixed is treated like position:absolute.

Comment: It doesn't seem so. The element stays fixed even when the page is scolled. This not the case for `position: absolute` elements